# Input Box to Select a Range or Enter Text

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA script that prompts a user for a range of cells containing keywords to be used later:

```
Dim keywordRange As Range
Set keywordRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range with your keywords.", "KEYWORDS", Type:=8)
```

This code works fine.  A pop-up box appears with a blank text field.  Click on a cell and the text field is filled with a reference to that range, for example, "$A$1".

I want the option to type text into that blank text field instead of selecting a range.  For example, the input box would return a range of "$A$1" if the cell was clicked or a value of "My Key Word" if the user typed it.

Currently, entering text other than a valid range reference generates this error:

> The reference you typed is not valid, or you did not provide a reference where one was required.  To enter a reference using the mouse, click in the edit box, and then click the cell in the sheet you want to refer to, or drag through the range you want to select.

I tried changing the the 'keywordRange' variable type to String.  That generated a compile error.

Any ideas where to start?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would recommend is create a `Userform` and place a `RefEdit` control as shown in the image below

[image]

And then use something like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range(RefEdit1.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You selected the range " & RefEdit1.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "You typed " & RefEdit1.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can type text or select a range as shown below.

[image]

Comment: This worked!  It was my first userform so I had to read up on their workings, but it did the job.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the type from 8 to 10

From Microsoft Docs:

> The following table lists the values that can be passed in the Type argument. Can be one or a sum of the values. For example, for an input box that can accept both text and numbers, set Type to 1 + 2.

Comment: This generated runtime error '424':  Object Required, at the Application.InputBox line of code.

Comment: Change `keywordRange` to `Variant`, you'll also want to do some checking on what type of answer was entered to avoid errors down the line

Comment: It won't work Michael :) OP says `the input box would return a range of "$A$1" if the cell was clicked or a value of "My Key Word" if the user typed it.` How will you output what was typed/selected?

Comment: Still no joy.  With keywordRange set to Variant and the type set to 10 it generates a couple of errors.  If selecting a range, a pop-up message says "Text is not valid." and allows me to try again.  That's Excel, not any error handling I built in.  If I enter text, the script throws run-time error 13, Type mismatch.

Comment: Michael, The dilemma  with `Type:10` is what would you choose? `Set keywordRange = Application..` or `keywordRange = Application...`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, You're right!  After investigating further, my solution doesn't work at all.  It seems silly, but I think having an input box to have the user decide which they want to enter then the appropriate type to handle their choice